# ARRAY. Is there a difference between $variable=[]; and $variable = array();

Tags: php, arrays

when clearing the cache with the console I got the following message.

```
PHP Parse error:  parse error in 
/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/Symfony/src/XXX/BlogBundle/Controller/BlogAdmArticleController.php 
on line 15
```

the line 15 is:

```
$variable = [];
```

why is this an issue while it works just fine when testing the code.

Comment: It depends on the version of your php. I think this `[]` is available in PHP <= 5.4.

Comment: @aldrin27 I think  is available in PHP >= 5.4